# Do AnyVal elements inside specialized collections need boxing?

Tags: scala, collections, long-integer, value-type, autoboxing

Say I have a custom class which extends `AnyVal` and uses a `Long` internally:

```
case class Instruction(underlying: Long) extends AnyVal
```

When I add `Instruction`s to a collection which is specialized for `Long`, do the `Instruction`s need boxing?

(Are there Scala collections which are specialized for `Long`? I need an indexed sequence.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it will be boxed. Unfortunately, value classes lose all their benefits when used as type arguments (generics) or put into collections. They are boxed *always* when they need to be seen as any other type than *exactly* the type of the value class itself.

The reason for that limitation is that to retain sound semantics of Scala language, code like this must work:

```
case class ValueClass(raw: Long) extends AnyVal
val someList: List[Any] = List[ValueClass](ValueClass(42L))
someList.head match {
  case ValueClass(raw) => // boxing needed for this match to work...
  case _ => ...
}
```

Specialization doesn't change anything here, any collection (specialized or not) could be passed somewhere where it's seen as `Coll[Any]` or `Coll[T]` where information about *exact* element type is lost.

If you want an `IndexedSeq[Long]` with unboxed storage, I think `scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.ofLong` is the closest thing to that. It also has its corresponding builder, `scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuilder.ofLong`.

Answer (score 0):

For now **Scala** doesn't support `@specialized` for **collection**.

> Currently there is no support for specialization of collections. It would be nice to allow this in the new design if we can do it without too much of an impact on the majority of non-specialized collections.

https://www.scala-lang.org/blog/2017/02/28/collections-rework.html

PS: I think this is caused by the **Java** doesn't support **primitive collection**, Since **Java** generiction is bound to the `Object` type, but **primitive type** doesn't derive from `Object`.